# Geocoder city fetch issue

Tags: android, android-location, google-geocoder

I am using google's geocoder class to fetch city with given lat-long.

I am facing this problem in India where earlier city name was `Banglore` and now it is changed to `bengaluru`.

So when I fetch using `geocoder.getFromLocation` method I get `Banglore` instead of `bengaluru`

While using the same lat-long I call [Geocoder api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%25s,%25s) directly, then I get the right city value i.e `bengaluru`.

Following is code geocoder class code

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        String city = null;
        if (geocoder != null) {
            if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(params[0], params[1], 1);
                    city = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

My target and compile sdk version is 23.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you checked all entries in `addressList` not (0) only ?! bengaluru could be there too

Comment: Yes i did. It has a single entry.

Comment: Can you post a sample latlng that shows the problem? Also, what is the value of Locale.getDefault() on your device?

Comment: Locale.getDefault() is en_US.
sample latitude = 12.9876172
sample longitude = 77.6192513